# R: Aggregate (from stats v3.6.2) does not work properly

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns. The first one identifies the document and is called "doc_id". The second column contains text that I have assembled from several columns and is called "text". The assembled text contains several sentences. There is noting else in the data frame. A sample could look like this:

My Problem is, that when I use the aggregate function (from stats v3.6.2), it doesn´t aggregate properly. Some lines are not aggregated or sometimes they are aggregated as a list and not as a single string.

**Starting Situation:**

```
    doc_id           text
1   1015328_1999     aaa aaa aaa.
2   1015328_2000     bbb bbb bbb.  
3   1015328_2003     ccc ccc ccc.
4   1015328_2004     ddd ddd ddd.
5   1015328_2005     eee eee eee.
6   1015328_2006     fff fff fff.
7   1015328_2006     ggg ggg ggg.
8   1015328_2006     hhh hhh hhh.
9   1015328_2006     iii iii iii.
10  1015328_2006     jjj jjj jjj.
```

**Result I want to obtain:**

```
    doc_id           text
1   1015328_1999     aaa aaa aaa.
2   1015328_2000     bbb bbb bbb.  
3   1015328_2003     ccc ccc ccc.
4   1015328_2004     ddd ddd ddd.
5   1015328_2005     eee eee eee.
6   1015328_2006     fff fff fff. ggg ggg ggg. hhh hhh hhh. iii iii iii. jjj jjj jjj.
```

I tried to used the following code:

```
> mydataframe <- aggregate(text ~ doc_id, data = mydataframe, paste, collapse = " ")
```

**But this is what I get instead:**

```
    doc_id           text
1   1015328_1999     aaa aaa aaa.
2   1015328_2000     bbb bbb bbb.  
3   1015328_2003     ccc ccc ccc.
4   1015328_2004     ddd ddd ddd.
5   1015328_2005     eee eee eee.
6   1015328_2006
```

Although there should be data for aggregation, the code does not. Sometimes it aggregates correctly, sometimes it aggregates but puts a list in a row instead of a string, and sometimes the values are missing completely.

Any help would be highly appreciated! 
Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT:**
Test data as code:

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- tribble(
  ~doc_id,      ~text,
  "1015328_1999", "aaa aaa aaa.",
  "1015328_2000", "bbb bbb bbb.",  
  "1015328_2003", "ccc ccc ccc.",
  "1015328_2004", "ddd ddd ddd.",
  "1015328_2005", "eee eee eee.",
  "1015328_2006", "fff fff fff.",
  "1015328_2006", "ggg ggg ggg.",
  "1015328_2006", "hhh hhh hhh.",
  "1015328_2006", "iii iii iii.",
  "1015328_2006", "jjj jjj jjj.",)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. Can you share your data using `dput` ?

Comment: what R version are you using?

Comment: Does `aggregate(text ~ doc_id, mydataframe, I)` work for you?

Comment: I am using Version 1.2.5033

Comment: I produced a file with dput but how can I share it? Sorry I am new here.

Comment: 1.2.5033 is almost certainly the version of RStudio, not R. `sessionInfo()` will print the R version (among other things).

Comment: You can copy the output of `dput()` and [edit] your question to paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a solution based on `tidyverse` not `stats`. If that is a problem or solution doesn't meet what you're trying to do, please let me know

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- tribble(
  ~doc_id,      ~text,
  "1015328_1999", "aaa aaa aaa.",
  "1015328_2000", "bbb bbb bbb.",  
  "1015328_2003", "ccc ccc ccc.",
  "1015328_2004", "ddd ddd ddd.",
  "1015328_2005", "eee eee eee.",
  "1015328_2006", "fff fff fff.",
  "1015328_2006", "ggg ggg ggg.",
  "1015328_2006", "hhh hhh hhh.",
  "1015328_2006", "iii iii iii.",
  "1015328_2006", "jjj jjj jjj.",)

group_by(test, doc_id) %>% summarise(text = paste(text, collapse = " "))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  doc_id       text                                                            
  <chr>        <chr>                                                           
1 1015328_1999 aaa aaa aaa.                                                    
2 1015328_2000 bbb bbb bbb.                                                    
3 1015328_2003 ccc ccc ccc.                                                    
4 1015328_2004 ddd ddd ddd.                                                    
5 1015328_2005 eee eee eee.                                                    
6 1015328_2006 fff fff fff. ggg ggg ggg. hhh hhh hhh. iii iii iii. jjj jjj jjj.
```

Comment: Hey zeebrah, thanks for your answer and effort! I tried your code but it isn´t working properly. The code is running all the time but I won´t get any output. Maybe this is because I have a large data frame with roughly 7000 rows.

I tried this code:
test <- tibble(mydataframe)
group_by(test, doc_id) %>% summarise(text = paste(text, collapse = " "))

Do you have any other idea, or what am I doing wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: @FelixOtto , I checked my code on 3 different systems (2 Macs running R 4.0.0 and R 3.6.1 and Windows machine with R 3.6.0). On every one my code seems to solve the problem you described. If it does fou you in the end, please accept my answer. Thanks. Also you should use `as_tibble()` to convert existing dataframe into tibble. `tibble()` is reserved for creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. It wasn't a coding error, but a display error. The RStudio viewer was not working properly. It displayed empty rows or cells when there was actually data in them.

As I used the code: utils::View(name of dataframe) I was able to see the full content.

Weird though. But thanks for all your help!

Best regards!